# MySQL - executing text file with unicode causes "question marks"

Tags: mysql, unicode

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (test VARCHAR(10));
```

`test.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('тест');
```

In bash:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
$ file -bi test.sql
text/plain; charset=utf-8
$ mysql --database=... --user=... -p --default-character-set=utf8 < test.sql
```

Results to

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------+
| test |
+------+
| ???? |
+------+
```

How to execute `test.sql` properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using utf8 as the default charset on the table itself so you're not using some sort of latin encoding default.

```
CREATE TABLE test (test VARCHAR(10)) DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Comment: + You can run 'SET NAMES UTF8' before your queries.

Comment: Does that also impact the database's table long enough to actual maintain that encoding on the next select? Very interesting point, I'm just looking to understand it a little better :)

Comment: ...It also specifies the character set that the server should use for sending results back to the client. (For example, it indicates what character set to use for column values if you use a SELECT statement.)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html